# Basic Properties of ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have just finished reading groups and move to rings . I have been thinking rings like a group with some extra features .Like for addition ring is a good abelian group and for multiplication it has some more or less properties . But I have some doubts ( Pardon me if these questions seems silly )

1. Can addition and multipication be any binary operation in ring ? Are '+ 'and '• 'are just symbols replacing Asterisk for any binary operation in  groups .
   Can addition be multipication and multipication be addition .

Is $a^2=a.a$ or $a+a$ ?

2. How can we prove that ring is closed for multiplication process ( Closure property ) . Because in definition it only follows associativity and distribution ?

Comment: Can you clarify question 2?

Comment: @razivo I am thinking that ring has one set and two binary operation , for addition it's abilion group and for multiplication it just has assositavity and Distribution with addition . But how we know that for two elements a, b in set R , a•b also belongs to R ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you give the definition of group you don't "prove" it is closed under multiplication, that's what happens if you have to show a certain set with an operation is indeed a group. Same thing for rings, there's no proof needed. You should observe that a binary operation on a set $A$ is a function $f: A\times A\longrightarrow A$ with some extra properties, thus closure is already assured by definition.

Generally in group theory we use the term "operation" and often denote the operation as "$\star$". But now in ring theory as you have $2$ operations, you need to give them a more proper name, hence $+$ and $\cdot$ come into play. Please notice "$-$" is not a binary operation, but rather a unary operation associating to an element its inverse. Writing $a-b$ is just a short form for $a+(-b)$.

The notation $a^{2}$ can be tricky sometimes. In a group this would depend on the operation you have, in a ring it always means $a\cdot a$ and not $a+a$.

Comment: So addition and multipication can be any binary operation in ring as long as they follow basic Properties of ring ?

Comment: Precisely. I suspect you are new to the subject, because it sounds "not general enough" to call general operation as "sum" and "multiplication". That happens because we use the same names on more "less general" objects as the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$. Although we use the same names, the operations are far from being the same.

Answer (score 1):

1. They have one main constraint, they have to be distributive.
   for every three elements in the ring, $a,b,c$, $(a+b)*c=ac+bc$.
   one of the main reasons multiplication can't be addition is because 0, it is rather easy to prove that multiplication by 0 is absorptive($0*a = (1-1)*a = a-a=0$).
   but this conflicts with it being a group, as it has to have an identity.

Comment: Consider set R with only one element {0} then are {R,+,×} and {R,×,+} rings ?

Comment: Yes they are. Not all authors agree on it actually, but you can see $\{0\}$ as the trivial ring where the $2$ operations are the same.

Comment: Sorry missed that exeption.